# Are individuals with controlled blood pressre still considered to have high blood pressure?

Tags: terminology, blood-pressure

I was reading this article:

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-03-18/99-of-those-who-died-from-virus-had-other-illness-italy-says

the TL;DR is that 99% of the Covid-19 deaths in Italy had other conditions.

One of the most common conditions was high blood pressure. I understand that they were older people and it is natural they have higher blood pressure.

Since these articles don't go in detail, I was wondering if the issue could be that:

- they had 'real' high blood pressure
- they had a high blood pressure 'condition', but it was under control
- as a third hypothesis, disease made blood pressure treatment impossible / not working

but my question is really about the first two points: we hear about risks of high blood pressure. But when this point is brought up, are we talking about the real blood pressure (as in uncontrolled) or the condition (regardless if it is under control)?

this point was never clear to me.